# How to get recent app's thumbnails from my own application?

Tags: android

How do I get other app's thumbnails just like recent app does?

I found that [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esdmobile.taskswitcher&hl=zh_TW) can do so.

It seems that one can get thumbnail form framebuffer with root permission.

However, I'd like to know how to do this without root permission.

Thank you very much!

Comment: have you tried anything ? like browsing the code of the android stock recent apps activity ?

Comment: android recent apps activity needs permission of system app.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with PackageManager. Nicely described in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11277774/2829009

Comment: Thanks. However, I am not trying to get an icon @@

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the list of the apps you installed.

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List appsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Then you can then call getIconResource() and get the icon resource of the install app.

For more info see [ResolveInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html) class.

Comment: Hi istovatis, Thanks for reply. What I am trying to get is not an icon but a thumbnail. It's like a screenshot for a running app.

Answer (score 0):

I finally knew we can use java reflection to call ActivityManagerNative.getTasks(int maxNum, int flags, IThumbnailReceiver receiver) to get other apps's thumbnails.

Comment: Great! Can you tell me how exactly did you called getTasks? I've tried  something like [this](http://codepad.org/1ct1BO5y) but it's throwing a NoSuchMethodException.

Comment: Ok, and how did you imported the IThumbnailReceiver class? I think it should be in android.app but it isn't there..

Comment: You can find IThumbnailReceiver.aidl in android source code.
path: frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/IThumbnailReceiver.aidl.

Just copy this file and put it in proper path in your apps.

Comment: I get `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` on the last line in your code.