# How to get dark android icons?

Tags: android, icons, android-theme, android-styles, android-menu

I have an item in menu.xml which should have a dark icon. When I use

```
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
```

I can see light version. How to use default dark icons?

Comment: Have you checked this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480075/actionbar-menu-default-icons)

Comment: I will ask another question. I have in sdk/platforsm/android-21/data/res/drawable-hdpi ic_menu_copy_holo_dark.png and ic_menu_copy_holo_light.png . How can I use them with default @android: prefix ?

Comment: See my answer below - you can do same way for using default light icons if default app style is dark.

Answer (score 1):

For instance if the default app style is Light and you want to use the default dark icons for the menu.xml, it can be done like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/edit" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_dark"
android:title="Edit" />
<item android:id="@+id/prefs" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_dark"
android:title="Settings" />
<item android:id="@+id/share" android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_copy_holo_dark"
android:title="Share" />
</menu>
```

Refer to [Android versions menu drawables](http://androiddrawables.com/Menu.html) for drawables details