# Trying to find a specific Icon in the android.R.class. Is there a preview of all the images?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to find a specific icon from the `android.R.class`. Specifically the check underline used in gmail notifications. I've tried opening the `R.class` but it doesn't preview the icons on the left.

[image]

Is there a way to view all the icon images instead of using them one by one like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preview the icons inside your `Android SDK`

Something like `Android SDK/platforms/android-X/data/res/drawable-hdpi/`

Here is a previous answer that should work the last one is the best.

[How to preview R.drawable.* images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905128/how-to-preview-r-drawable-images)

For Windows Solution:

The full path is

`C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-31\data\res\drawable-hdpi`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Note for windows users: The android SDK is the AppData folder which is hidden so try typing in the path instead of looking for the folder

Comment: A full list of the icons (I also found the one I was looking for here, which was not inside the Android Sdk) https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material+Icons